# Uncaught ReferenceError: {function ONCLICK} is not defined at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have one page `index.php` and the other one `include/comments.php`.

index.php

```
<div class="row replybox" style="display:none">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <textarea class="form-control" id="rComment" cols="30" rows="2"></textarea><br>
        <button style="" class="btn-primary btn" id="addReply">Add Reply</button>
      </div>
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
   function reply(x) {
      $('.replybox').show();
   }
 </script>
```

include/comments.php

```
function DisplayComment($data){
  return '
           <div class="comment">
               <div class="useremail">'.$data['email'].' <span class="date_time">'.$data['date'].'</span></div>
               <div class="comment">'.$data['comment'].'</div>
               <div class="reply"><a href="#" onclick="reply(this)">REPLY</a></div>
               <div class="replytext"></div>
           </div>

            ';

}
```

When I click on the reply link,
the following error is displayed

> ReferenceError: reply is not defined
> at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick

I am not able to show the div ($('.replybox').show();)...
Can someone help me.
thank you.

Comment: Make sure Javascript is added at the end of page

Comment: @Viney Do you mean I need to add javascript in comments.php as well ?

Answer (score 0):

I think it seems like there is an error in the connection. because you have assigned href to the a tag and the onclick event. I will recommend you to try as follows.

```
<div class="row replybox" id="replybox" style="display:none">
<div class="col-md-12">
    <textarea class="form-control" id="rComment" cols="30" rows="2"></textarea><br>
    <button style="" class="btn-primary btn" id="addReply">Add Reply</button>
  </div>
</div>



function DisplayComment($data){
 return '
       <div class="comment">
           <div class="useremail">'.$data['email'].' <span class="date_time">'.$data['date'].'</span></div>
           <div class="comment">'.$data['comment'].'</div>
           <div class="reply"><button type="button" onclick="reply()">REPLY</button></div>
           <div class="replytext"></div>
       </div>

        ';

}
```

and please try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function reply() {
        document.getElementById('replybox').style.display = "block";
      }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks but Still same error "ReferenceError: reply is not defined at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick"

Comment: Yes like `function DisplayComment($data){
  return ' <script type="text/javascript">
             function reply(x) {
               $('.replybox').show();
             }
  </script>
      <div class="comment">
           <div class="useremail">'.$data['email'].' <span class="date_time">'.$data['date'].'</span></div>
           <div class="comment">'.$data['comment'].'</div>
           <div class="reply"><button type="button" onclick="reply()">REPLY</button></div>
           <div class="replytext"></div>
       </div>`

Comment: Thanks @Viney... I figured it out, when i add return reply() it works.  <div class="reply"><a href="#" onclick="return reply(this)">REPLY</a></div>